Is it possible to disable the Query Compilation Cache in Redshift?
Redshift has two caches of interest; Query Result Cache and Query Compilation Cache. For this question, I am only interested in the Query Compilation Cache. For control and testing purposes, I need to turn this off sometimes. Is it possible, and if so, how?
